# Setting initial perm size and maximum perm size to the same to prevent full GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Is the author suggesting that setting the initial perm size and maximum perm size values to the same value can prevent full GCs from happening?

> A memory space, either Old or Permanent, is full and to accommodate new objects or classes, it needs 
>   to be expanded towards its max size, if the relevant parameters have different values. In other words, if 
>   ‐Xms and ‐Xmx have different values and if the size of Old needs be increased from ‐Xms towards ‐Xmx 
>   to accommodate more objects, a FullGC is called. Similarly, if ‐XX:PermSize and ‐XX:MaxPermSize have 
>   different values and the Permanent Space needs to be increased towards ‐XX:MaxPermSize to 
>   accommodate new java classes, a FullGC is called. **This can be avoided by always setting ‐Xms and ‐Xmx** 
>   **as well as ‐XX:PermSize and ‐XX:MaxPermSize to the same value**.

Java Performance Tuning Whitepaper:
http://mfinocchiaro.files.wordpress.com/2008/07/java-virtual-machine-neutral.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think he is saying that.

But I don't think he is right.  Certainly, I don't recall ever having seen this mentioned in any official Sun / Oracle documents.

Note that:

- The linked "white paper" is not an Oracle / Sun document.
- The author is not an Oracle / Sun employee.
- The paper is rather old, and refers to Java 4 and Java 5 JVMs.

It should be possible to get evidence one way or the other for this by turning on GC logging and seeing if there is a correlation between full GCs and heap expansions.

---

I have (often) heard that setting the initial and max heap sizes to be the same reduces JVM warmup overheads.  It is the assertion / implication that each heap expansion is preceded by a full GC that I am dubious about.